# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'cf710c6e-dfcc-

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-analysis-services

I keep on getting this error:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'cf710c6e-dfcc-4fa8-a093-d47294e44c66'.
```

[image]

Getting this error in Visual Studio in an SSIS project. In my project I added an Analysis Services Processing Task to my control flow.

When I start to edit the Analysis Services Processing Task, Authentication window opens I sign in then the above error is presented.

This has never been a problem. This started 1 day ago. Cant explain why.

I have update the following
Visual Studio 2019 + Data Tools and extensions
SQL Management Studio

Any help will be much a appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The current error message you are facing is due to the retirement of old client libraries. Microsoft shared the following warning to customers that were using older versions of client libraries:

*Analysis Services client libraries version 19.12.3.0 or higher offers important security enhancements, so any applications that are still using earlier versions of the Analysis Services client libraries will not be supported after 30 June 2021.
Action required
To minimize risk and potential security vulnerabilities, please update your Analysis Services client libraries to version 19.12.3.0 or higher before 30 June 2021.*

However, ( I believe ) the actual implementation date was on the 5th of July.

**If you are facing issues connecting using SSMS/SSIS/VS:**

1. Update the AS Libraries to the latest version from Analysis Services client libraries | [Analysis Services client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions#download-the-latest)
2. Update your SSMS to the latest version v18
3. Make Sure you have the latest updates for SSIS

**If you are facing any issues with connecting using Excel:**

4. Please check if you are using Excel’s MSI version or the ClickToRun version (This can be found using File > Account and About Excel)
5. If using MSI version, directly downloading the latest AS client libraries and upgrading them can help mitigate the issue (latest versions can be downloaded here: [Analysis Services client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions#download-the-latest)) “same as SSMS”
6. If using the ClickToRun version, please install the latest Office updates to help push the latest AS OLEDB libraries
7. One quick solution to help mitigate the issue, is to download and
   install the latest client drivers and then copy from "AS OLEDB\140"
   folder into the Excel ClickToRun’s ASOLEDB\140 folder and test if it solves the issue. Please take a backup of the existing ASOLEDB folder within MS Office.

Copy From:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\140

To:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesX64\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\140\   [If 64-bit]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesX86\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\140\   [If 32-bit]

Comment: Hi Everton,
I have implemented all the above as suggested, but still hasnt resolved my issue. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it'd be a good idea to install all the libraries from the documentation if you not already did.

Comment: Hi @JonathanBes I update SSMS v18 with the lastest version and the Analysis service dll and now everything is working. I suggest you to check in your SSMS propeties ( Help/About) the version of "Microsoft Analysis Client Tools" it's 15.0.19535.0 for me now.
Here all my information :SQL Server Management Studio : 15.0.18384.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) :16.100.46367.54
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools  :15.0.19535.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) :10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML :3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework :4.0.30319.42000
Operating System :10.0.17763

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well when I updated to SSMS 19 from 18.  For me, I solved it by going to Tools-> Options -> Azure Cloud and changing some settings.

```
Allow single signon to SQL using AAD authentication -> True 
Use system default web browser -> False 
Use web account manager -> False 
Name -> AzureUSGovernment
```

Make sure you set this last option (Name) correctly for what cloud environment you are connecting to. For me, it was a government cloud, but for you it probably just AzureCloud