# Error connecting to Azure Analysis Services - (file 'pfadalauthinfo.cpp', function PFAdalAuthInfoConfigurationWrapper::GetInstance')

Tags: excel, azure-analysis-services

We use two-factor authentication (2fa/mfa) to connect to the Azure Analysis Services (AAS / SSAS). Recently, some users have been getting this error message in their Excel 2019

```
file 'pfadalauthinfo.cpp', function PFAdalAuthInfoConfigurationWrapper::GetInstance'
```

[image]

They have an Excel file connected to the cube. Usually they just click refresh and the prompt opens up to login via 2fa (Okta), like in image below. Instead they receive the pfadalauthinfo.cpp error (the login prompt doesn't even appear)
[image]

They are on Office 2019 (Version 1808 (Build 10382.20010)) and Windows 10. These users have been able to connect in the past but no longer. In some cases, they previously connected on their laptop but can't connect after receiving a new laptop.

For one user, we attempted to overwrite the drivers (per these articles ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302360/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/462446/aadsts50011-error-occured-when-some-users-want-to.html)) but that didn't work. We discovered if we switch them Office 365, it connects perfectly. We can't do this for every user and Office 2019 should work. This seems like a bug in Office or the driver. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked with Microsoft support directly and they found an issue with the client libraries, namely the MSOLAP. New versions were posted to the site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions

We tested and all is well now.

Comment: Thanks for working with Microsoft support directly!

Per docs:

`MSOLAP
A regression related to connections to cloud-based systems using AAD was discovered in the 16.0.4.17 version of OLEDB (MSOLAP). It was fixed in the 16.0.20.201 version. Due to the nature of
the issue, an installed 16.0.4.17 version, as well any other version prior to 16.0.20.201, cannot be corrected by simply upgrading the provider, even if setup is run in repair mode. It’s recommended to completely uninstall the 16.0.4.17 [or other problematic] version and then install the 16.0.20.201 or later version.`

Comment: @Gabe - I am facing similar issue and I have 16.0.5109.0 installed from today as a latest version. I tried to uninstall all driver and install this one but it didn't work. Which versions do you have an is it still working?

Comment: Is it the same exact error? If not, you'll prob want to create a new question